# How to disable the left speaker?

Tags: windows-10, audio, dell-xps

I have a Dell laptop with Windows 10. There are two speakers: left and right. I can change the balance between them by right-clicking on the volume icon at the taskbar, then going to sounds -> levels -> balance.

When both left and right volumes are high, there is a strange noise coming from the left speaker; when I change the left volume to 0, the noise disappears. The problem is, when I later change the volume from the master volume setter (or from the keyboard), the left volume increases again.

Is there a way to set the volume of the left speaker to 0 permanently?

Answer (score 0):

External or internal speakers?

- If external, just unplug the left speaker, or cut the wire to it, or, better, put a 250 or 500 ohm variable resistor (potentiometer or "pot") in series with the center lead, which will allow *some* sound, up to the point of distortion.
- If internal, you'd need to open the case, find the wire to the left speaker, and do to it as shown above.

Comment: If it's outputting stereo sound, you will lose the left audio channel so you will miss an entire audio channel. By changing the balance you basically merge the two audio channels into a single mono channel. So these hardware modifications do not do the same thing as change the balance in Windows.

Comment: Correct, but apparently, that is acceptable. By putting a resistor in series, *some* left channel; sound would get through.

Comment: Sounds scary.. I might damage the electronics if I am not careful enough

Comment: Yes, you could destroy the laptop just by opening the case incorrectly. You know best your level of competence.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a hardware problem, you could try the following methods to see if the issue can be resolved.

**Method 1 Switch from Stereo to Mono**

Open your Settings from start menu

Click on Ease of Access

From the left pane, go for Audio and here you can see the option to Turn on mono audio.
Now let’s see if there is any improvement.

**Method 2 Re-install audio drivers**

Right-click on your start button or press the Windows logo key + X and select Device Manager.

Expand Audio Inputs and Outputs

Right-click on your Audio device (the same one in the playback devices list) and click Uninstall device.

After the uninstallation, head to your laptop manufacturer’s official website and search for the latest Audio driver for your machine. Download it, install it and then perform a reboot to make sure it’s activated.

Comment: Method 1: I switched Stereo to Mono, and indeed the sound sounds different, but the noise persists (apparently the Mono mode mixes the two channels, so the noise is still there).

Comment: Method 2: I installed the latest driver from the laptop manufacturer, but in the "Events" tab of the "Properties" box, I got the messages "device started - device configured - device not migrated". not sure what it means. Does it mean that the installation failed?